# How to connect nodes of two docker containers in elixir?

Tags: docker, erlang, elixir

I am trying to connect 2 nodes of different docker containers.

Container1: `iex --name abc@172.17.0.2 --cookie foo`

Container2: `iex --name xyz@172.17.0.4 --cookie foo`

Now lets say I want to connect to `abc@172.17.0.2` from `xyz@172.17.0.4`

Container2:

```
iex(xyz@172.17.0.4)> Node.connect(:"abc@172.17.0.2")

iex(xyz@172.17.0.4)> true
```

Nodes are getting connected. But if I do

```
iex(xyz@172.17.0.4)> node  = "abc@172.17.0.2"

iex(xyz@172.17.0.4)> Node.connect(:node)

iex(xyz@172.17.0.4)> false
```

Why I am getting error? This is happening with other functions as well such as Node.spawn/2.

Comment: and what about `node  = :"abc@172.17.0.2"` and then `Node.connect(node)`

Comment: Advice : do not use IPs, use names and let docker auto link your containers.

Comment: @Pascal, approach will work, i just tested it

Comment: @Pascal, Tarun Thanks!! It worked. See my answer for another way to solve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I got it working by converting the string into atom.

```
iex(xyz@172.17.0.4)> node  = "abc@172.17.0.2"

iex(xyz@172.17.0.4)> Node.connect(String.to_atom(node))

iex(xyz@172.17.0.4)> true
```

Comment: You are correct in your solution of it needing to be an atom.  However, you can specify the same functionality like: `:"abc@172.17.0.2"`.  Good luck!